# How to be warned when jwt expires?

Tags: vue.js

I need to be warned when the jwt expires (my default is 30 min), can someone please help me?, I want the user to be warned and be redirected to the login page

```
    const isInRole = (role: string): boolean => {
      try {
        const jwt = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (jwt) {
          var user = jwtDecode<User>(jwt);
          if (typeof user.roles === "string") return user.roles.toLowerCase() === role.toLowerCase();
          return user.roles.some(r => r == role);
        }
        return false;
      } catch (ex) {

      }
      return false;
    };

//here´s where I check the jwt value
    const isAuthenticated = () => {
      try {
        const jwt = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (jwt) {
          jwtDecode<User>(jwt);

          return true;
        }
      } catch (ex) {}
      return false;

    };
    const getJWT = () => localStorage.getItem("token");

    http.setJWT(getJWT());
```

Could you tell me what I´m missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the token has expired when you load the token from local storage, but before you set the token within the application's state:

```
let token = localStorage.getItem("token")
let payload = jwtDecode(token)

// payload.exp should contain the expiration epoch set upon creation
if (payload.exp > Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)) {
  alert("Your token has expired!")
}
```

If you do not have an expiration field but have an "issued-at" (`iat`) field, the following logic will also suffice for checking if it has been 30 minutes since it was issued:

```
const TIME_DELTA = 30 * 60 * 1000; // convert 30 minutes to epoch time 
if (payload.iat + TIME_DELTA <= Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)) {
  alert("Your token was issued more than 30 minutes ago!")
}
```